# Python - allowing circular imports

Tags: python

Is there some option in Python to allow circular imports?  I'm responsible for deploying someone's code, it's full of various bad practices including circular imports.  Naturally, when I run it, I get Exceptions.  I've fixed all of them before to test there aren't any other problems, and it does then run fine. This isn't a question about the specifics of circular imports themselves, I fully understand why they shouldn't be there, how to property fix them, workarounds etc.

They have demonstrated it will run on their machine somehow without throwing an exception, but I'm not allowed access to their configuration, or to change their code in production - I'm only allowed to deploy.

Code sample below exhibiting the same pattern/error (sorry, I'm not allowed to paste the actual code, but this is the nature of the problem):

a.py

```
from b import function_b

def function_a():
    print("a")
```

b.py

```
from a import function_a

def function_b():
    print("b")
```

and the error will look something like:

```
python3.9 a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from b import function_b
  File "/private/tmp/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a import function_a
  File "/private/tmp/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from b import function_b
ImportError: cannot import name 'function_b' from partially initialized module 'b' (most likely due to a circular import) (/private/tmp/b.py)
```

Comment: How does the code work in the first place then?

Comment: Circular imports are already allowed by default. You would have to go to specific effort to disable them. That's not the problem.

Comment: The problem is that circular imports intrinsically lead to subtle, nasty initialization order issues. There's no magic button to make those go away.

Comment: I don't understand how they would work in the first place, as far as I know a circular import will always through an exception. The guy writing the code isn't going to cooperate.   Having demonstrated it runs on his machine, it's now solely my problem unfortunately!

Comment: @Chris Can you add the traceback for the error you are getting and the code that is causing it? If the code does not run then your coworker has no choice but to cooperate

Comment: Thank you @IainShelvington, good point!  I've posted a sample that matches the error/issue 1:1, hope this helps

Comment: "as far as I know a circular import will always through an exception" - not true. Circular imports don't automatically throw exceptions. Circular imports cause initialization order issues, and those issues lead to exceptions. If, by careful design or by fluke, you manage to arrange things so stuff is always initialized before anything looks for it, you can have circular imports that work, but it's generally better to avoid the circular imports.

Comment: In the code you've posted, `function_a` is not defined before `from a import function_a` looks for it, hence the exception. In the code you're trying to deploy, we can't tell what's going on. *Something* must be different between your attempt and the other developer's environment, but we can't tell what the difference is or whose fault the issue is.

Comment: There's many instances, and some of them are slightly different - but this matches the majority of them exactly. Two modules, importing each others functions, in that order

Comment: That would have failed on the other developer's machine. You're missing something important. Maybe a subtle, crucial difference you don't spot because you don't know enough to realize its importance. Maybe something simple, like maybe the other developer is running a newer version of their code and you're looking at an old, buggy version, or maybe what they ran didn't actually load any of the problematic modules.

Comment: Are there any conditional imports in the code? First step is to figure out if/how this runs successfully.